# Get all Checked Items from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get / count all checked items from `DataGrid`. I've 20 items in `DataGrid` as you can see in below pic. Out of 20, visible items are 14 or 13. When i mark checked on all items by clicking **Select All Button**, all 20 items gets mark checked. but when i count checked items by clicking **Print Button**, the counting shows it mark just 14. what the matter? kindly help

[image]

Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="265" Margin="10,74,0,0" 
                  Name="GridTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="766" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell">

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="#0073c4"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Select" Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Code}"/>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

SelectAll Button:

```
private void SelectAllBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridTable.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = GridTable.Items[i];

        Item itemm = (Item)GridTable.Items[i];
        itemm.IsSelected = true;

        var mycheckbox = GridTable.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;

        if (mycheckbox != null)
        {
            mycheckbox.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Print Button click:

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < GridTable.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = GridTable.Items[i];

        if (GridTable.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox != null)
        {
            var mycheckbox = GridTable.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;

            if ((bool)mycheckbox.IsChecked)
            {
                count++;
                listTobePrint.Add(tableList[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

Note: this  `MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());`
counts 14

Item.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inventory_Control.Classes
{
    class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string id;
        private string code;
        private string name;
        private string description;
        private string quantity;
        private string availableQuantity;
        private string unitprice;
        private string subtotal;
        private string category;
        private string type;
        private string location;
        private string index;
        private bool _isSelected;

        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
        public string Code
        {
            get { return code; }
            set
            {
                code = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Code");
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
        public string Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set
            {
                quantity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }
        public string AvailableQuantity
        {
            get { return availableQuantity; }
            set
            {
                availableQuantity = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AvailableQuantity");
            }
        }
        public string UnitPrice
        {
            get { return unitprice; }
            set
            {
                unitprice = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
            }
        }
        public string SubTotal
        {
            get { return subtotal; }
            set
            {
                subtotal = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SubTotal");
            }
        }
        public string Category
        {
            get { return category; }
            set
            {
                category = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Category");
            }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set
            {
                type = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
        public string Location
        {
            get { return location; }
            set
            {
                location = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }
        public string Index
        {
            get { return index; }
            set
            {
                index = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Index");
            }
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your DataGrid uses row virtualisation. It is telling you the truth - it only has 14 selected rows because that is all it needs to present your underlying data.

The CODE magazine article [*XAML Anti-Patterns: Virtualization*](https://www.codemag.com/article/1407081/XAML-Anti-Patterns-Virtualization) has a great explanation.

I notice you haven't databound your DataGrid, you must be adding the rows programmatically? The correct (proper) way to access your selected items is to go to your viewmodel that contains the collection of `Item` objects that you've bound the DataGrid to, and iterate that collection to find the selected items.